# Not able to load example.pl from browser

Tags: apache2.4

I have installed apache webserver in ubuntu and created `example.pl` in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

I have also add below code to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

From `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` when I execute `./example.pl`
I'm getting output, but when i tried to load perl script from browser using `localhost/cgi-bin/example.pl`, I'm getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Please help me in resolving this issue, i know it is simple but i don't what to do to fix it

Comment: There are a few troubleshooting steps given in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/560749 - try them out.